# Renaming a batch file and keeping part of the filename

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename

I've seen plenty of posts on similar requests but I can't quite  find one that suits what I am trying to do.  It is fairly simple but I cannot seem to get it.

```
ren FILE??.txt FILE%Year%%Month%%Day%??.txt


copy FILE%Year%%Month%%Day%??.txt C:\Users\me\Desktop\Batch\renamed\achod%Year%%Month%%Day%??.txt
```

I cannot get the script to keep the '??' which represents random characters the first file may have.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are the `??` characters always in the same position (the 5th and 6th) in the file name and always exactly two characters?

Comment: yes, it will always be the 5th and 6th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to rename files directly using a wildcard character. Instead you need to locate all the applicable files and then rename each.

The script below works under the assumptions of your question/comments:

- File name is 6 chars long.
- Only the last 2 chars are interchangeable.

Of course, the script could be very easily adapted to accomodate other settings but this does just as you requested.

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Set your Year, Month, Day variable values here.
REM They will be used for file renaming.
...

CD "C:\Path\To\Files"

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%A IN (`DIR "File??.txt" /B /A:-D`) DO (
    REM Extract the last 2 chars of the file name.
    SET FileName=%%~nA
    SET First4=!FileName:~0,4!
    SET Last2=!FileName:~-2!

    REM Rename the file, inserting the new data.
    RENAME "%%A" "!First4!%Year%%Month%%Day%!Last2!%%~xA"
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: This seems to work well.  I was mistaken and the file name is actually 7 characters, 5 and then the last 2.  I changed the SET FIRST4 to FIRST5 and 0,5 and it seems to work fine.  Thanks for your help!!